# Summing $\sum^n_{k=1} \frac i {2^k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Could someone help me sum following series as $n$ goes to infinity:
$$\sum^n_{i=1} \frac i {2^i} = \frac 1{2^1} + \frac 2{2^2} + \frac 3{2^3} +\cdots+ \frac n{2^n}$$

I don't need the answer so much as being pointed towards what I need to know to figure out the answer...I assume there are different ways to do it. I used to know this stuff a long time ago but don't know where to begin now. Thanks...

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) may give you some ideas.

Comment: This is a recurring question here.  I've answered it several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the fact that $\dfrac{n}{x^n} = -x \cdot \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{1}{x^n}\right)$ to evaluate $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{x^n}$, and then substitute $x=2$.

Comment: Well, I can see that n/x^n=−x⋅(d/dx)[(1/x^n)] is true, but I"m afraid I don't know how to proceed when I sub that into the summation expression. If I distribute the summation across -x and (d/dx)(1/x^n) does the summation work like an integral and cancel out the (d/dx)? My calculus is pretty shaky right now!

Comment: No, but you can interchange the summation symbol and the differential operator to get
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{x^n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( -x \cdot \dfrac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{1}{x^n} \right) \right) = -x \cdot \dfrac{d}{dx} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^n} \right)$$

Comment: Ah. Thanks....think I got it. In general, how do you make the first step? I mean, how do you "see" that n/x^n can be replaced by the expression -x * d/dx(1/x^n)? I can tell it's true once you suggested it, but how does one know to start there?

Comment: Lots of practice.

Comment: My thought was: there's an awkward $n$ multiplying everything, we might be able to get rid of it by looking at the summand as a derivative. (And the reason I thought this was... lots of practice.)

Answer (score 1):

Easier hint:
$$
\begin{array}{ccll}
\sum_1^\infty\frac{n}{x^n} &=& \frac{1}{x^1} + & \frac{1}{x^2} + &\frac{1}{x^3} + \ldots \\
&+& & \frac{1}{x^2} +& \frac{1}{x^3} + \ldots \\
&+& & & \frac{1}{x^3} + \ldots \\
&+& \cdots 
\end{array}
$$
Each of these is a simple geometric series (for example, row 2 sums to $\frac{1}{x^2} \frac{1}{1-1/x}$).

But each of those series is $1/x$ times the one above it.  So you have a second geometric sum to do.

Comment: Clever! thanks.